# Query a column and change value to numeric value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012. I have a table which contains a column `MyCol` which can only be the four values below:

```
MN
ABB
BO 
BN
```

When I query the data from my table I want to change these values to a numeric value instead, so say MN = 1, ABB = 2, BO = 3 & BN = 4.

How do I do this using a select statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple `CASE` statement will do:

```
SELECT
    CASE MyCol
       WHEN 'MN' THEN 1
       WHEN 'ABB' THEN 2
       WHEN 'BO' THEN 3
       WHEN 'BN' THEN 4
    END
FROM
    dbo.Yourtable
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
Case When MyCol = 'MN' Then 1
     WHEN MyCol = 'ABB' Then 2
     When MyCol = 'BO' Then 3
     When MyCol = 'BN' Then 4 End as MyCol
From MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to add a computed column:

```
alter table t
    add MyColInt as (case MyCol
                       when 'MN' then 1
                       when 'ABB' then 2
                       when 'BO' then 3
                       when 'BN' then 4
                     end);
```

You can guarantee the correctness of the values:

```
alter table add constraint ck_MyCol check (MyCol in ('MN', 'ABB', 'BO', 'BN'));
```

However, I would advise you to create a reference table for the abbreviation.  The reference table can have the number, the full name, and perhaps other information.  A foreign key reference then guarantees that the values are correct.